# How do i set up constraints for SE and 6S+ when their both treated as w:compact h:regular

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout, xcode8, xcode8-beta6

Using xcode 8, im trying to set up constraints to handle iPhone SE - iPhone 6s+ screen sizes.

Now, using Phone 6+, I've set up my constraints manually, and boy does it look beautiful on an actual device. This was pretty each with 6s+ and 6s since the extra space isnt *that* much.

So now im on to the SE constraints. There is so little space to work with but I manage to make it work buy shrinking some fonts.

Now, hear is the part that stumped me... I switch back to 6s+ only to find out my beautiful UI was replaced with the super tiny SE sizes. why? beacause from `6s+` - `4s` are all treated as `w:Compact, h:Regular`.

Maybe im overlooking something super simple? Maybe this is a horrible design flaw? IDK. What i do know is that the new traits system was supposed to make it easier for universal storyboards. So my question is how do i set up constraints for each device size?

---

#### My Beautiful 6+ UI

[image]

#### My Beautiful SE UI

[image]

#### And heres when i switched back to my 6s+

[image]